# How to stop closing a jaoptionpane when the option button click

Tags: joptionpane

Guys i wanna add a password option pane in to my project

```
    String password;
    JTextField jtf = null;
    JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField();
    passwordField.setEchoChar('*');
    JOptionPane jop = null;

    Object[] obj = {"Please enter the password:\n\n", passwordField, jtf};
    Object stringArray[] = {"OK", "Cancel"};
    if (jop.showOptionDialog(null, obj, "Confirm",
            jop.YES_NO_OPTION, jop.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, stringArray, obj) == jop.YES_OPTION) {

        System.out.println("OK");
    } else {
        System.out.println("CLOSE");
    }
```

i wanna stop closing this pane when button clicks please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
   while(true){
    if (jop.showOptionDialog(null, obj, "Confirm",
            jop.YES_NO_OPTION, jop.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, stringArray, obj) == jop.YES_OPTION) {

        System.out.println("OK");
    } else {
        System.out.println("CLOSE");
    }
}
```